# Not able to kill a jackdbus

Tags: jack, killall

I was trying to install `jackd` and the installation with apt gave two commands: `jackd` and `jackdbus`. I tried to execute `jackdbus` and it ran in the console. When I tried to terminate it by <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, it is not getting killed. I also tried `killall jackdbus` but it has not effect at all. How can I kill it? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `kill -9 <pid>` to kill the process. `killall <processname>` sends only SIGTERM to all the processes.

You need to send SIGKILL and for that first find `<pid>` using `ps -ae | grep '<processname>'`. Then issue the above mentioned kill command for all the processes that are listed by `ps` command.